# Playing video directly from the camera roll, is it possible?

Tags: ios, ios6, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am running in this issue for few days. I need to pick a video from my camera roll and play it directly in my app. What i want to know is simply: Is it possible or not? because my code below doesn't play the video after i pick it from the camera roll, and i doubt that i may need to save the video in local before playing it back.

My relevant code is below:

```
//...
if (CFStringCompare((CFStringRef)mediaType, kUTTypeMovie, 0)==kCFCompareEqualTo) {
    NSString *moviePath=[[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]path];
    NSURL *movieURL=[NSURL URLWithString:moviePath];
    self.mpController=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:movieURL];

    NSLog(@"%@",moviePath);
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self
                                            selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                                name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                              object:self.mpController];

    self.mpController.movieSourceType=MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
    self.mpController.controlStyle=MPMediaTypeMusicVideo;
    [self.mpController prepareToPlay];
    [self.mpController.view setFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [self.mpController setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:self.mpController.view];
    [self.mpController play];


}
[[picker presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

//...

-(void)moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification{
    NSLog(@"moviePlayBAckDidFinish");
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [notification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     removeObserver:self
     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
     object:player];

    if ([player
         respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)])
    {
        player.fullscreen=NO;
        [player.view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

**P.S**: The notification handler `moviePlayBackDidFinish` always gets called after compressing video and i got a blank screen. Also, logging the `moviePath` variable gived me this kind of path:

```
/private/var/mobile/Applications/5912AED1-S1DE-25EF-A8B-EF7AD21E3R65/tmp//trim.‌​uUcGJU.MOV
```

As i said, i think i doubt that playing videos directly from the camera roll is not possible. But I need you to confirm. Thanx.

Comment: Have you verified `movieURL` is not `nil`?

Comment: Hi, it's not nil, as shown above in the `P.S`. I got something like: `/private/var/mobile/Applications/5912AED1-S1DE-25EF-A8B-EF7AD21E3R65/tmp//trim.‌​uUcGJU.MOV`

Comment: You said that was `moviePath` which was why I specifically asked about the URL.

Comment: Oh sorry, ok here is the movie url: `/private/var/mobile/Applications/5912AED1-S1DE-25EF-A8B-EF7AD21E3R65/tmp//trim.‌​‌​uUcGJU.MOV`

Comment: I got the same result for both movie url and path